# JS. Как сделать, чтобы последняя ссылка была null, a не undefined?

Tags: javascript, рекурсия, объекты

```
var arrayToList = function(array, index){
    if(index < array.length){
        return {
            name: array[index],
            rest: arrayToList(array, index + 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (index < array.length) {
  ...
} else
  return null;
```